# Compare multiple values in dicitionary to avoid duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, airtable

I'm using Airtable to store some data. On a regular basis I need to import data from csv into it but as the data doesn't match in structure I plan to do it via Python which I'm not that familiar with yet.

I need to check for duplicates before importing the data so I thought while iterating through my imported CSV and reformatting data to my needs I should also check if the respective row is in there yet.

Here's what the table for Airtable looks like:

```
{'id': 'recNEnwdnREAw9', 'fields': {'field1': 'data1', 'field2': 'data2'}, 'createdTime': '2017-10-18T15:27:32.000Z'}
```

And here's what my data looks like

```
{'nr': 1, 'date': '2017-10-18', 'test': '1324wefwlerj', 'amount_eur': '40,00'}
```

This is highly simplified, there are more fields in each set.

I don't have any single unique value to compare so I would need to see if field1 and field2 match to the row that I'm currently at in my local data. That's where I'm getting lost. Do I need to iterate through the whole set of Airtable data by one field and then look at the second one from the results? This doesn't sound very effective to me and I'm sure there's a better way!

Thanks for helping

Comment: A python dict does not store any duplicates. If you add a value that already exists an exception is raised.

Comment: @mrCarnivore: not necessarily. If you use mydict[key] = value, it will override the already present value for that key.

Comment: @Tobias Brösamle: You are right, me comment was not precise: If you add a value to an existing key, the old value will be overwritten. If you add a key that is already in the dict then (and only then) it will raise an exception!

Comment: " If you add a value that already exists an exception is raised." how that would ever happen?

Comment: I think you would like to assure key and value pair is unique, take a look at `set`.